# NSLineBreakMode ByWordWrapping is not working after latest update

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

After the latest update I have noticed the the following is no longer working in Swift. I am not getting any errors, but it is just not word wrapping anymore, any thoughts or any ideas what has changed that has effected this and how I can resolve this?

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    var topic : getTopics
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    topic = storedTopic[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = topic.parsestopic
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    return cell
}
```

As mentioned, I am not getting errors and everything is populating, just word wrapping is no longer working :(

What is happening instead of displaying this which is in the output screen:
"Please nod if your answer is yes and shake your head if your answer is no"

This is the output:
[image]

I am getting this
[image]
Regards and thanks in advance
Andrew

Comment: what is happening instead? lines are breaking but within words?

Comment: for me this code is working totally fine in a UITableViewController... in my example it set the **topic** var to be a very long string... no problems!

Comment: and are you using a predefined cell style or a custom one? since you are using the textlabel property i guess you are using the predefined Basic, right?

Comment: yes I am, as I said this worked prior to swift 1.2 updated on the 7th of April. I have noticed that there is a new release Build: 6D1002

Comment: take a look at my demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n3lwsls090jibcl/AABhpzNMxSqIzxbO_5nALtf1a?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved.....

There was nothing wrong with the code. Looking at the settings, I found that the prototype cell setting was set to custom and the indentation was set to 1 and 0.

Not 100% sure if the indentation or the prototype cell type was the attributor but changing this to basic, and setting the indentation to 0 and 10 now displays the contents as it should.

Very weird as this was not something I remember ever changing.

Regards
Andrew